# How do you customise lxml objectify to parse INF as a string instead of a float?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

With python lxml and objectify, it converts the `INF` into a float.  Is there a way to output `INF` as a string instead of a float?

```
from lxml import objectify


value='''
    <outside>
        <inside>INF</inside>
    </outside>
'''
root = objectify.fromstring(value)
inside = root.inside 
print inside, inside.__class__
```

Output:

```
inf <type 'lxml.objectify.FloatElement'>
```

Comment: You could add [type annotation attributes](http://lxml.de/objectify.html#type-annotations) or use [XML Schema](http://lxml.de/objectify.html#xml-schema-datatype-annotation).

Answer (score 0):

Set the [`pytype` attribute](http://lxml.de/objectify.html#type-annotations) on the `inside` tag:

```
<outside xmlns:py="http://codespeak.net/lxml/objectify/pytype">
    <inside py:pytype='str'>INF</inside>
</outside>
```

Demo:

```
>>> from lxml import objectify
>>> value = '''
...     <outside xmlns:py="http://codespeak.net/lxml/objectify/pytype">
...         <inside py:pytype='str'>INF</inside>
...     </outside>
... '''
>>> root = objectify.fromstring(value)
>>> inside = root.inside
>>> print inside, inside.__class__
INF <type 'lxml.objectify.StringElement'>
```